# Regex pattern to match all words of a phrase while accepting quote (') in between but NOT in First or End of word

Tags: javascript, regex

Been looking for a couple of days now and still could not get my head around it.

This is the phrase,

```
const phrase = `"That's the password: 'PASSWORD 123'!", cried the Special Agent.\nSo I fled.`;
```

and this is the expected transformation,

```
['that's', 'the', 'password', 'password', '123', 'cried', 'the', 'special', 'agent', 'so', 'i', 'fled']
```

The **first element (*that's*)** of the array is the problem area.

I can only get below transformation,

```
['thats', 'the', 'password', 'password', '123', 'cried', 'the', 'special', 'agent', 'so', 'i', 'fled']
```

Using below code

```
const cleanPhrase = phrase.replace(/["':!,.]/g, '').replace(/[\n]/g, ' ').toLocaleLowerCase()
const words = cleanPhrase.split(' ');
```

Is there a way to ignore the single quotes on `'Password 123'` but accept the single quote on `that's` ?

Answer (score 1):

First i think it is better to use [**String.prototype.match()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) instead of split.
Then there is 2 simple methods for that:

###### A) Without using [look-behind](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#:%7E:text=Positive%20and%20Negative%20Lookbehind)

```js
const phrase = `"That's the password: 'PASSWORD 123'!", cried the Special Agent.\nSo I fled.`;
console.log(phrase.match(/(?!')[\w']*\w/g));
```

[**Live try**](https://regexr.com/6eaos)

###### B) Using look-behind ([Check browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#browser_compatibility))

```js
const phrase = `"That's the password: 'PASSWORD 123'!", cried the Special Agent.\nSo I fled.`;
console.log(phrase.match(/(?!')[\w']+(?<!')/g));
```

###### Explaination

- `\w` = `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`
- `[\w']` a character set/class + `'`

  - `*` Zero or more length (Of the set)
  - `+` One or more length (Of the set)
- `(?!')` Check if in first of your ahead is not a `'`
- `(?<!')` Check if in last of your behind is not a `'`

Note: In first method `[\w']*` can be zero or more so for checking ahead of that, i use a char length class (`\w`) without the quote `'` to i can avoid of using negative look-behind and also support even one character words like `I`

Answer (score 0):

I would first replace all quotes that are surrounded by letters with a "placeholder"... That is a character that should not appear in the string. I used a pipe (`|`)  in the example below.

```js
const phrase = `"That's the password: 'PASSWORD 123'!", cried the Special Agent.\nSo I fled.`;

const cleanPhrase = phrase

  // Replace all quotes with a placeholder
  .replace(/(\w)'(\w)/, "$1|$2")
  .replace(/["':!,.]/g, "")
  .replace(/[\n]/g, " ")

  // Restore the quotes where there is a placeholder
  .replace(/(\w)\|(\w)/, "$1'$2")
  .toLocaleLowerCase();
const words = cleanPhrase.split(" ");

console.log(words);
```

Comment: How about, "'Twas the second time he borrowed Chris' car"? Distinguishing between single quotes and apostrophes is notoriously difficult.

Answer (score 0):

First replace all the symbols with an empty string,
then replace  `'`, `'`  and `\n` with a single space:

```js
const phrase = `"That's the password: 'PASSWORD 123'!", cried the Special Agent.\nSo I fled.`;
const words = phrase.replace(/["!.:,]/g, '')
  .replace(/\s\'|\'\s|\n/g, ' ')
  .toLocaleLowerCase().split(' ');
console.log(words);
```

You could also use split instead of the second replace:

```js
const phrase = `"That's the password: 'PASSWORD 123'!", cried the Special Agent.\nSo I fled.`;
const words = phrase.toLocaleLowerCase()
  .replace(/["!.:,]/g, '')
  .split(/\s\'|\'\s|\n|\s/g);
  console.log(words);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a short solution like

```js
const phrase = `"That's the password: 'PASSWORD 123'!", cried the Special Agent.\nSo I fled.`;
console.log(phrase.match(/\w+(?:'\w+)*/g).map(x=>x.toLowerCase()));
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/NLtZSk/1).

The `/\w+(?:'\w+)*/g` regex matches all occurrences (`g` flag stands for gloval) of one or more word chars followed with zero or more sequences of `'` and one or more word chars.

Comment: @ceving See "*expected transformation*" in the question. OP needs `that's`. See the question: *Is there a way to remove single the single quote on `'Password 123'` but keep single quote on `that's`?*